# Grow and shrink the input

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking for a way to control the size of my `input` element in the way similar to divs.

```css
.main {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.line {
  min-width: 2rem;
  display: flex;
}

.input {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  min-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="line">
    <input class="input" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Here I am expecting that when the view appears the initial input is of size `2rem` (padding, margin, border do not matter here) and when you start typing and exceeds the size it grows till it reach the size of `main`. Any suggestions how I can achieve that?

Comment: The input won't change based on the content entered. You'll probably need to use javascript for that.

Comment: You might also look into using `contenteditable` instead of an `input`

Comment: @redouglas yeah, definitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another solution using the `.getBoundingClientRect()`, so the idea is to add the text of the input to a p element calculate the width of it then set it as the width of the input, this keeps using the same input instead of **content editable trick** that a user can press enter and have multiple lines, also can be used in forms...

```js
var txtElement = document.querySelector("#hidden-text");
document.querySelector(".input").oninput = function() {
  txtElement.innerHTML = this.value;
  var width = txtElement.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  this.style.width = width < 100 ? 100 : width + "px";
};
```

```css
.input {
  width: 100px;
}
#hidden-text {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#hidden-text, .input {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="line">
    <input class="input"/>
  </div>
</div>

<p id="hidden-text"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

An example using only CSS and the `contenteditable` attribute:

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
}

.line {
  display: flex;
}

.input {
  border: 1px solid lightslategray;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 1em;
  min-width: 30ch;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="line">
    <p class="input" contenteditable></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is great, very helpful

Comment: Be aware that I'm not sure if use max/min width in flexbox is a good idea. It works, but it might not be best practice.

Comment: Thank you evolutionxbox. Looks nice except that when it grows over the parent, the parent grows, but I expected that it stop growing and behavior like input with 100% width in this case. Do you have an idea how to make it?

Comment: You can probably set a max width on the parent?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the most efficient solution, but you could do something like this:

```js
document.querySelector('.input').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    let span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerHTML = e.target.value;
    span.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    span.style.fontSize = '15px';
    document.body.appendChild(span);
    if (span.offsetWidth > e.target.offsetWidth - 10) {
        e.target.style.width = span.offsetWidth + 'px';
    }
    span.parentNode.removeChild(span);
});
```

```css
.main {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.line {
  min-width: 2rem;
  display: flex;
}

.input{
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  min-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<div class="line">
  <input class="input"/>
</div>
</div>
```